# JPA concat operator

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, concatenation, jpql

Is there a JPA concat operator for string concatenation?

I know there is a JPA `CONCAT` function, however its ugly to use for concatenating multiple strings.

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(cola,colb),colc),cold)
```

Vendors like Oracle offer `||` some other like Microsoft offer  `+`. Is there a standard JPA concatenation operator so that I could create a query like

```
cola || colb || colc || cold
```

I tried `+` using openjpa with SQL Server, however it seems to be invalid JPQL. I couldn't find anything regarding such an operator in an [oracle reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function was extended in **JPA 2.0** to allow passing more than 2 parameters, from section 4.6.17.2.1 (String Functions) of the specification:

```
CONCAT(string_primary, string_primary {, string_primary}* )
```

In JPA 1 this was restricted to exactly two parameters.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf lists this function as you described it. Openjpa 2.1.1 should be JPA 2.0.

Comment: OpenJpa 2 should support this syntax, can you post the exact query and the exception you are receiving?

Answer (score 11):

You can use JPA Concat function for multiple strings.

For example:

```
CONCAT(cola, colb, colc, cold)
```

Comment: Checked that. I get an exception with openjpa. The reference I linked (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_string_fun) shows only two arguments as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `||` as a concatenate operator, see [on the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html)

> HQL defines a concatenation operator in addition to supporting the
>   concatenation (CONCAT) function. This is not defined by JPQL, so
>   portable applications should avoid it use. The concatenation operator
>   is taken from the SQL concatenation operator - ||.
>
> Example 11.19. Concatenation operation example
>
> ```
> select 'Mr. ' || c.name.first || ' ' || c.name.last
> from Customer c
> where c.gender = Gender.MALE
> ```