# Error Unexpected token '%' : JPQL - LIKE %FUNCTION(:namedParam)%

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I get Unexpected token '%' when use this JPQL query: In my case I use the upper function but it could be anyone.

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE %UPPER(:asunto)% ")
public Entity namedMethod(@Param("asunto") String asunto));
```

I need to add LIKE %:param% to find any coincidence of the param inside my text.

Have tried :

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE '%'UPPER(:asunto)'%' ")
```

Unexpected token: UPPER

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE '%UPPER(:asunto)%' ")
```

Unexpected token: UPPER

No luck in there either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [JPQL Concat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504457/jpa-concat-operator)

Comment: Thats it thanks @M.Prokhorov!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPQL Like Case Insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178520/jpql-like-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, there are two ways to resolve this problem:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:asunto) || '%' ")

@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(UPPER(:asunto),'%')) ")
EDIT-- Thanks to @Nicolau: 
@Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%',:asunto,'%'))")
```

Both works!

Thanks to @M.Prokhorov.

Comment: Simpler: @Query("SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE UPPER(s.asunto) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%',:asunto,'%'))")